# Check if the specific cron-job is active

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering whether if I can check a specific cron job is working or not.  For example, I would like to send myself an email if the *wpse_twicedaily_cron* and *wpse_oncedaily_cron* is not active/ running in the WP.
I can setup the email, but I just need to figure out how to detect if certain cron job is active. I will need to check if the cron jobs are working every 5 minutes.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To view all scheduled tasks, you can use the code below that utilizes `_get_cron_array()`. Sample code is taken from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/simple-testing/)

```
function bl_print_tasks() {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>';
}
bl_print_tasks();
```

You can then create your hook and function and add it as a cron to wordpress.

```
add_action( 'wpb_custom_cron', 'wpb_custom_cron_func' );
 
function wpb_custom_cron_func() {
  // Check whatever here and then email
  wp_mail( 'you@yourdomain.com', 'Cron Alert Email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress to test certain cronjobs');
}
```

To add your own cron or simply see / trigger other crons, you can use [WP Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) plugin. Here is how to add your cron from `Tools » Cron Events`

[image]

Screenshot and sample mail code taken from [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-view-and-control-wordpress-cron-jobs/)

Comment: Hi, I got inspired by your answer and now I'm checking if the certain cron job isnot working via (!in_array("name_of_cron", _get_cron_array())). But the issue is it keeps emailing me because the cron is set to minute, the  name_of_cron keeps going away and coming back in _get_cron_array(). So, What I would need is to check if the name_of_cron has ran more than once in the last 5 minutes.Any solution?

Comment: Hi @NishDekardo, I didn't look at the contents of _get_cron_array(). If it lists just cron names, then the other cron data should be somewhere else.